# Google Artifact Registry: Unable to publish package with the same version even after package deletion

Tags: npm, google-cloud-platform, google-artifact-registry

I'm trying to publish npm package to the google artifact registry (GAR).

A package with the same version has already been published, but I've deleted it manually from the GAR.

```sh
npm view <package-name>@0.1.3

<empty response>
```

But still unable to publish the package.

```sh
npm publish

npm ERR! code E400
npm ERR! 400 Bad Request - PUT https://<package-url> - Requested version(0.1.3) already exists.
```

Looks like it has been cached somewhere. If so is there any possibility to clear the cache?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually Cloud Artifacts Registry does not allow that, according to [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/nodejs/manage-packages#add):

> You can only publish a specific version of a package once. This is an npm restriction to ensure that the contents of a published package version are always the same. As a result, you cannot:
>
> - Overwrite a package version by publishing it again to the repository
> - Remove a package or its version from the repository, and then publish a package with the same name and version number

So you are going to have to create another version in order to publish the package.

Comment: This makes perfect sense for public packages, but with a private registry, I've expected a bit more flexibility. But anyway, thank you for your answer.

Comment: No problem, glad to help, btw, you could make a case for this being changed, if you'd like, by opening a feature request in [Google's Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187156&template=0), so it can be considered by their product team.

Answer (score -1):

**Warning**: this is NOT a solution for existing repositories that contain quite some packages and their versions!

There's still a way to do this, BUT it requires deleting and recreating the whole repository.
So:

1. Delete the whole repository
2. Recreate the repository with the same name and options.

Comment: Delete a whole repository!